# Tax_Query using WP_Query not working

Tags: wp-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries, tax-query

I cannot get this query to work properly. It just renders one post even though I have three posts that are categories in the 'Firm News' and 'Test' categories.

Can anyone see a problem with my code?

```
<?php
            $myquery = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                         array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array('test', 'firm-news'),  
                    )

                ),
                'posts_per_page' => 5, 
                'orderby' => 'RAND', 
);



            $m = new WP_Query( $myquery );

            if ( $m->have_posts() ) : $m->the_post();?>

                <ul><li <?php post_class();?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li></ul>
             <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Afaik the `relation` only works if you got multiple arrays/arguments. Have you tried moving the second term to another arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't looping through the results. Here is your code:

```
$m = new WP_Query( $myquery );

if ( $m->have_posts() ) : $m->the_post();?>
       <ul><li <?php post_class();?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li></ul>
<?php endif; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

There is no Loop. You just check for the existence of posts, echo some information about the first one and quit. `if` is not a Loop. It is a conditional. You need [`while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php).

You need:

```
$m = new WP_Query( $myquery );

while ( $m->have_posts() ) : $m->the_post(); ?>
       <ul><li <?php post_class();?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li></ul>
<?php endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```